# Mechanism for synthesis of benzofuran

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds

Would someone be able to help me with the mechanism for the synthesis of benzofuran from salicyladehyde (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzofuran)? I have got as far as the decarboxylation step.

[image: Synthesis of benzofuran]

Comment: Which decarboxylation step? A lot of reactions there! Benzofuran 2-carboxylic acid?

Comment: I agree with @user55119, it would help if you were a bit more explicit. Consider also sharing what you've done so far -- so that people can see where you got stuck and pick up from there.

Comment: I presume there is some heating for the decarboxylation step as benzofuran-2-carboxylic acid is commercially available..